# How to change a php variable every 3 seconds?

Tags: php

```
<?php
        $sites = array('http://site1.net', 'http://site2.fr');
        ?>


        <script>


            function loadwebsite() {
                <?php
                    foreach ($sites as $site) {
                        $disp = echo $site;
                    }

                ?>
            }
            setInterval(loadwebsite, 3000);
        </script>
```

I want that my page displays the url of a website, changing every 3 seconds, like an auto surf....
For example the first 3 seconds, it displays http://site1.net
... and for 3 seconds, after 3 seconds, it displays http://site2.fr
and alternatively...
But I don't succeed to do that...

EDIT: I do it in javascript

```
<script>

        var sites = ['http://site1.net','http://site2.fr'];

        function loadwebsite(site) {
            document.getElementById("site").innerHTML = site;

        }
        for (var i=0;i<=1;i++) {
            site = sites[i];
            setInterval(loadwebsite, 3000, site);
        }

    </script>
```

I want to display one website from my array, changing every 3 seconds but I don't succeed to do that. How to do that ?

Comment: hui.... many strange things here: 1. mixing javascript & php (in js-function loadwebsite), 2. that line `$disp = echo $site;` will be an error, doesn't make sense.

Comment: you should do this without any php.

Comment: you wanna do a true location change between those two sites, or just "display the url"?

Comment: I want to display one url from the array, which changes every 3 seconds

Comment: You're entirely misunderstanding the difference between server-side code and client-side code.  All of the PHP *in its entirety* executes before the page loads in the browser.  Look at the page source in your browser to see what `loadwebsite()` actually does every 3 seconds.  Aside from that, it's not really clear what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @jeff I edited my code to do it in javascript . But me it does not display one website per seconds. How to fix the problem ???

Comment: follow the answer @KIMB-technologies gave!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following code:

```
<script>

    var sites = ['http://site1.net','http://site2.fr', 'http://site3.org/'];
    var sitekey = 0;

    function loadwebsite() {
        document.getElementById("site").innerHTML = sites[sitekey];
        if( sitekey == ( sites.length - 1 )){
            sitekey = 0;
        }
        else {
            sitekey++;
        }

    }
    setInterval(loadwebsite, 3000);
    loadwebsite();
</script>
```

`setInterval` runs the function `loadwebsite` every 3 sec, without taking car of the for loop.
You have to choose the link in the function `loadwebsite`.
I also run `loadwebsite` the first time without `setInterval` to show the link imedently on startup.